# Can I override a CUDA host-and-device function with a host-only function?

Tags: compiler-errors, cuda, overriding, virtual-functions, nvcc

Consider the following program:

```
class A {
    __host__  __device__ void foo();
};

class B : A {
    __host__ void foo();
};

int main()
{
    A a; (void) a; 
    B b; (void) b;
}
```

This [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/UNJKOp) (GodBolt) with nvcc 10.

Yet, in more complex programs, I sometimes get the following error (line breaks for readability):

```
whatever.hpp(88): error: execution space mismatch: overridden entity (function
"C::foo") is a __host__ __device__ function, but overriding entity (function "D::foo")
is a __host__ function
```

So, nvcc is telling me that I'm *not* supposed to drop an execution space when overriding methods. I'm not asking about my own code (which I haven't cited here), but about the principle:

- If it's acceptable to override `__host__ __device__` functions with just `__host__` functions (which I find reasonable) - then how can nvcc even have such an error?
- Alternatively, if it's not allowed - why is the small program above compiling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Overriding (virtual) methods must respect execution space choice of the overridden method.

"overriding" is only relevant to virtual methods - so it must be the case that your `C::foo()` is **marked `virtual`**. And indeed, if we mark `foo()` in the example program as virtual:

```
class A {
    virtual __host__  __device__ void foo();
};

class B : A {
    __host__ void foo(); // can say "override" here; but it doesn't matter
};

int main()
{
    A a; (void) a; 
    B b; (void) b;
}
```

This will [*fail* to compile](https://godbolt.org/z/wEbten):

```
<source>(6): error: member function declared with "override" does not override
a base class member
```

Does this limitation make sense? One could imagine an interpretation in which the base-class method will apply to `__device__`-side calls, and the subclass method to `__host__`-side calls. But that too is a bit awkward - and we need to call *something* when acting on an object via a base class ptr.